# Getting around file access protection in Windows to view an active logfile read-only

Tags: .net, winapi, log4net

A customer asked for quick and dirty log viewer for an ASP.NET app, for which I'm using log4net, and I thought somehow we could simply add a controller to read the tail of the active file and spit it back.

If I use the standard .NET API (File.OpenText, etc.) I get access violation (file open by another process), which is what I expect, but I know it is possible to read the file because Ultraedit opens it for viewing read-only. Can I do the same from the .NET API?

```
using(StreamReader infile =
         System.IO.File.OpenText(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\log\my.log"))
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a file even when getting an "in use by another process" exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400517/how-can-i-read-a-file-even-when-getting-an-in-use-by-another-process-exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify That you allow read/write sharing on the file, and put a StreamReader on your stream to get the same behaviour as `File.OpenText`.

```
using( Stream stream = File.Open(@"x:\path\file.log", 
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite) )
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        //read content
    }
}
```

And since you can open the file with UltraEdit, I assume log4net is not putting an exclusive lock on the file.

Comment: But you want to open the file which log4net creates. Since ultraedit can read it, then the file is not under exclusive lock by log4net, and you should be able to access it as well with .Net specifying the FileShare parameter. It could also be that your asp.net process don't have access rights to the actual file.

Comment: Well that worked, where using the basic OpenRead or OpenText did not!

Comment: "Since ultraedit can read it, then the file is not under exclusive lock" - Right, I knew as much, but I assumed that OpenRead and OpenText would use similar access modes, but apparently they do not.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try:

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("C:\\1.txt"))
        {
            //read here
        }
```