# PowerShell: waiting for output redirect file to unlock after killing process

Tags: powershell, process, file-locking, start-process

I have a PowerShell script that:

- Starts a new process and redirects the output to two files
- Waits with a timeout for the process to complete
- Kills the process if it timed out
- Reads the contents from the redirected output files

It looks something like this:

```
$_timeout = 30
$_stdoutfile = "./stdout"
$_stderrfile = "./stderr"

# Start the process
$_process = Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file ""$_cmdfile""" -PassThru -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError "$_stderrfile" -RedirectStandardOutput "$_stdoutfile"

# Wait for it to complete, or time out
$_timeout_error = $null
$_process | Wait-Process -Timeout $_timeout -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable _timeout_error

# Check if it timed out
if ($_timeout_error) {
    # Kill it
    $_process | Stop-Process -Force

    # (1)
    # Wait for the process to exit after the kill command
    $_kill_timeout_error = $null
    $_process | Wait-Process -Timeout 10 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable _kill_timeout_error

    # If the process is still running 10 seconds after the kill command die with an error
    if ($_kill_timeout_error) {
        Write-Error "Failed to terminate process (waited for 10 seconds after initiating termination)."
        Exit 1
    }
}

# (2)
# Read the stdout and stderr content that was output
$_stdout = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$_stdoutfile")
$_stderr = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$_stderrfile")

# Delete the files after reading them
Remove-Item -Force "$_stdoutfile"
Remove-Item -Force "$_stderrfile"
```

The majority of this works properly; the process is killed as expected if it runs too long. The problem I'm having is with the `ReadAllText` functions. They work fine if the process exits on its own, but if they were killed due to a timeout, these functions fail with the error:

```
The process cannot access the file 
'C:\myfilename' because it is being used by another process.
```

I figured that perhaps it takes the OS a couple seconds to unlock the files after the process is killed, so I inserted a sleep-poll loop at `# (2)`, but often several minutes later, they're still locked.

@Santiago Squarzon suggested (in the comments) a way to read the file while it's still locked, which may work, but I also need to be able to delete them after reading them.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to get these files to naturally unlock more quickly after killing the process?
2. Is there a way to force-unlock these files with a separate PowerShell command/function?
3. Unrelated, but is the part in my code around the comment `# (1)` necessary (waiting for the process to stop after the kill command), or will `Stop-Process` block until the process is actually stopped?

Comment: Kinda C# but I hope you get the point https://stackoverflow.com/a/4400546/15339544 you need to target [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-filestream-ctor(system-string-system-io-filemode-system-io-fileaccess-system-io-fileshare)). As aside, I believe `Get-Content` get's around this issue did you try?

Comment: I did try with `Get-Content`, it had the same error. That post you linked, it looks like it's for reading a file that's still locked. I'd prefer to just unlock it though, as I also need to delete it after I read it.

Comment: I'm not sure if PowerShell has a built-in solution for this, however you could look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle